# c++ Skip first line of csv file

Tags: c++, csv, getline

I got my program to read from a .csv file and output the data but I don't want it to output the first line. I've tried to use `getline(data, line);` and `stream.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );`. While it does skip the first line, the last two lines print twice and are mixed up.

```
string ID;
string sentenceIn;
string servedIn;
int sentence;
int served;
string lastName;
string firstName;

vector<string> idNum;
vector<string> sentenceLen;
vector<string> servedTime;
vector<string> lastNameIn;
vector<string> firstNameIn;


ifstream data("prisoner_data.csv");

if (data.is_open())
{
    cout << "File opened successfully." << endl << endl;
    while (data.good()) // !someStream.eof()
    {
        getline(data, ID, ',');
        cout << ID << "  ";
        idNum.push_back(ID);

        getline(data, sentenceIn, ',');
        cout << sentenceIn << "  ";
        sentenceLen.push_back(sentenceIn);
        istringstream(sentenceIn) >> sentence;

        getline(data, servedIn, ',');
        cout << servedIn << "  ";
        servedTime.push_back(servedIn);
        istringstream(servedIn) >> served;

        getline(data, lastName, ',');
        lastNameIn.push_back(lastName);
        cout << lastName << "  ";

        getline(data, firstName, ',');
        firstNameIn.push_back(firstName);
        cout << firstName << "  ";
    }
}
```

What can I do to skip the first line without messing up the last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `while (data.good())` is fishy. You end up "eating" one more line. See e.g. [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/3093378) for more details. You usually have to test the result of `getline` directly in the `while`, like

```
while(getline(data, line)){...}
```

One possible solution is to read the file line by line with `while(getline(data, line)){...}` then use a `stringstream(line)` and for each line, parse it with `getline` again, now separated by `,`. To skip the first line just do a `getline(data, line);` before, then follow up with `while(getdata(data, line)){ /* process line */}`. A simple example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{     
    std::ifstream data("prisoner_data.csv");
    if (!data.is_open())
    {
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::string str;
    std::getline(data, str); // skip the first line
    while (std::getline(data, str))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(str);
        std::string token;
        while (std::getline(iss, token, ','))
        {   
            // process each token
            std::cout << token << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. However, I need the `sentence` and `served` to be integers. How do I convert them using this way?

Comment: @Andre You can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert a string to an integer.